# Creating a customized page for displaying only folder structure of Alfresco Share

Tags: alfresco, freemarker, alfresco-share, web-scripting

i have a requirement where i have an integration of my java application with alfresco share such that when a user clicks on a button , i need to give the user a custom page where he can select the folder structure of alfresco , how do i create a custom alfresco page where the user is able to view the folder structure of alfresco ? is there a better option to achieve it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new custom page in alfresco share is not so hard.
This tutorial helps you to create the custom page

http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/developer/2013/02/21/simple-page-creation-in-share/

I am wondering why you need to create a custom page with the folder structure. Alfresco's repository is a folder structure itself. So why not give the destined user the rights to view the repository structure of alfresco?

(I don't know how to show the folder structure in a customized page. I don't see any reason to build it though)

Answer (score 0):

If allowing the user visibility of the alfresco Share interface is not an option, then you'll need to create a custom webscript which outputs the repository structure.

This multi-part guide details exactly how this would be achieved through webscripts:
http://docs.alfresco.com/3.4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.Enterprise_3_4_0.doc%2Fconcepts%2Fws-folderListing-intro.html